# Question about implementation inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I noticed the following code in one project.

Header:

```
class scheduler {
public:
    void add_task(task* t);
    void run();
};
```

Source:

```
class scheduler_impl : public scheduler {
public:
    void add_task(task* t);
    void run();
private:
    std::vector<task*> tasks;
};

void scheduler::run() {
    scheduler_impl* impl = (scheduler_impl*)this;
    impl->run();
}
```

The line "scheduler_impl* impl = (scheduler_impl*)this;" raises concerns, and I have a feeling that it can be replaced with PImpl.

Am I correct in understanding that this is done to avoid interfaces with purely virtual functions and to avoid the overhead associated with virtual table lookups?

If there is a specific term for this, could you please let me know?

Comment: ` scheduler_impl* impl = (scheduler_impl*)this;` ehr no... this is not the correct way to implement the pimpl pattern. You need something like : std::unique_ptr<scheduler_impl> m_impl; And that belongs in the constructor of scheduler. NEVER use "C" style casts to make one class type look like another (the same is almost always true for "C++" casts too). Also make "task" moveable (or use a std::shared_ptr) so you don't have to work with raw pointers to tasks. For such a small bit of code there is a lot to improve.

Comment: The word you're looking for is Undefined Behavior... after the "C" style cast anything goes, your program is no longer in a correct state.

Comment: It's not very specific, but the term is silent UB generator. Use with caution because I can think of several very simple ways to make this explode.

Comment: Your understanding seems correct.

Comment: In my understanding the main goal of the PImpl pattern is not so much efficiency improvements, but keeping you external interface clean. External code including your public header does not need to know anything about your internals. This reduces interdependency.

Comment: @nick Yes that is the goal of the pimpl pattern, it is also known as a compilation firewall. The "scheduler" class should only have a forward declaration of the pointer to implementation and its header file is what other classes will see (so very clean, no complex members). The implementation class can then use whatever types it needs and be quite complex and changing it will not affect client code (doesn't need recompiling)

Comment: @kiner_shah He is only correct in the sense that no virtual methods will be needed. But the overhead is there anyway virtual functions or not (there is always an indirection). The big difference with interfaces (abstract baseclasses/virtual functions) is that a pimpl pattern can instantiate itself, with interfaces it is more common to use factory methods.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I was just surprised by this casting in the C-style.  I decided to find out from more experienced comrades what it’s called 

Comment: @PepijnKramer, right, got it.

Comment: @Max I would also be surprised by that. Hope you got the answers you were looking for ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: it is not necessary UB, but requires that the object is actually a `scheduler_impl`. So additional code would be required to have that guaranty (factory, deleted copy constructor, ...).

Comment: @Jarod42 You are correct, but that is quite unlikely with the example OP has shown here  ;)